# Bash command for displaying the list of finished jobs

Tags: cluster-computing

I am using a computer cluster to run simulations in parallel. Is there a command (Bash) which can produce a list of finished simulations?
Thank you.

Comment: Under which scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using slurm on your cluster, you can use sacct to get statistics on completed jobs

```
sacct -u <username> --format=JobID,JobName,MaxRSS,Elapsed
```